# rename Computer's - good idea to do so in a Win Server 2016 environment?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am on a Windows domain (Server 2016 my to become DC). I have noted that it would be possible to go to *>Acitve Directory Users and Computers >My Business >SBS Computers* and change a Cmputer's Name using the General tab of the properties.

- Is it a good idea to do that remotely like that, or are any bad sideeffects to be expectd (like ending up with computer accounts for the same physical Computer i.e.)?
- can the client conintue to word which processing this operation?
- Is it generally a good idea to change Computernemes of machines whicht are part of a domain at all?

Comment: Actually I don't believe the general tab provides that capability, but no it is not a good practice. A computer rename should be performed on the computer, and restarted to take effect.

Comment: ok @GregAskew , but generally changing the computername (on the computer itself & restart it as you say) when you are a domainmember and also connected to a Server (using the "Client Connector for Windows Server Essentials") isn't a problem?

Comment: Provided that you change the computer's name the right way, i.e., on the computer itself using the System Properties control panel, and provided you have the right privileges in the domain to update the computer object (e.g., if you are a domain administrator) then renaming a computer is not normally a problem.  It is possible that SBS is a special case - I've never used it - but I wouldn't expect it to be.

Comment: so, @HarryJohnston the computer object in the domain has to be (manually) updated after a change of a Computer's name (on `Server 2016 Standard`, the SBS will be burried shortly)?

Comment: No, the control panel updates the computer object for you.  But you have to have the permission to do it.

Comment: ok, got it, thx